# Prevent body from scrolling on mouswheel, but not the texarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mousewheel

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/cB3jZ/15/

When you scroll to the bottom of the textarea with your mousewheel, it continues to scroll the rest of the page.. How can i prevent that!?

When i mouseover the textarea i could disable scrolling intierly with this script:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770179/973485
But i still want the textarea to be scrollable.

http://jsfiddle.net/cB3jZ/15/

Hope you can help! :=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the it only continues scrolling if the outer container if it is the body tag. So if you this it works!

```
<style>
   body,html {height:100%;}
   #fakeBody {height:100%; overflow:auto;}
</style>
<body>
<div id="fakeBody">
    <!-- popup with a textarea inside -->
</div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cB3jZ/34/

Comment: +1 Good find, and no JS involved either. Confirmed to work in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Using the jQuery mousewheel plugin:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('textarea')
        .bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {      
            if (this.scrollHeight && this.scrollHeight <= $(this).height() + $(this).scrollTop() && delta < 0){ 
               event.preventDefault()
            } else if($(this).scrollTop()===0 &&  delta > 0){
               event.preventDefault()
            }
        });
});
```

I have to warn you that it doesn't work in IE7 or older (but it doesn't throw errors, so its cool)

http://jsfiddle.net/cB3jZ/36/

Comment: Thanks! But that throws me to the top of the page, when im scrolling in the textarea :(

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly! But i think i'm gonna use the javascrip free version :)